# How to find inverse of a complicated function?

Tags: functions, inverse

It is usually easy to find inverse of function when we can solve in terms of $x$ & $y$. However, what should I do when I have functions like $y=x^5+2x^3+x-1$ and $y= \cos(x)+3x$?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, "find" the inverse ? Are you looking for a closed form ? If so, why do you think there is a closed form ? Or do you just want to prove that the inverse exists ?

Comment: I would change the title from "complex" to something else like "non-obvious", complex would suggest functions defined on complex numbers

Comment: El Mehdi, all you need to know is that most inverses do not have a "closed form." This does not always present problems. In calculus, one may always find the derivative of an inverse function if the original function can be explicitly differentiated. In that case, it is just that the graphs of $y=f(x)$  and $x=f(y)$  are mirror images across the line $y=x$

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers. Sorry i dont have a strong background on calculus, thus i dont know what does it means closed form but i met this in an exercice f(x) = cos(x)+3x i must evaluate at f(1) and f'(1) and also inversef(1) and inversef'(1).
I know that to find the inverse function there is 2 steps (swap y and x and solve for y), but how about when we can't solve for y ?? like these two examples ?

Comment: @ElMehdiAKKOUCHE Maybe you can answer the questions *without* finding *explicitely* the inverse of $f$... Did you compute $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ ?

Comment: El, please read my earlier comment

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry I must evaluate f(x) at x=0, it leads to f(0) = 1 and f'(0) = 3, for the other question i swapped x & y to have x = f(y) = cos(y)+3y the implicit differentiation gives dy/dx = 1/(-sin(y)+3 ) but i can't evaluate it at 1, what is sin(1)??? and the anwser is 1/3 what is going wrong ?

Comment: @ElMehdiAKKOUCHE The fact that $f(0)=1$ should give you some information about $f^{-1}(1)$...